# FluentAssertions WhenTypeIs double.NaN

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I have two complex objects, with diferent types inside(objects, strings, doubles, etc). I want to compare them by using the following code:

```
myActualObject.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(myExpectedObject, options => options
        .Using<double>(dbl => dbl.Subject.Should().BeApproximately(dbl.Expectation,
         ABS_ERROR))
        .WhenTypeIs<double>()
    );
```

I am trying to compare the double type property values using the `.BeApproximately` behaviour, but does not work correctly because of one special case:

- Sometimes I have a `double.NaN` inside the double, and comparing a NaN with another NaN gives an assertion fail(because of the BeApproximately behaviour). How can I skip the comparison, or make it true in this case?
- And lastly, how can I print the name of the object that caused the assertion fail?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT >>>>**

I've found a first approach(thanks to @Sam Holder):

```
myActualObject.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(myExpectedObject, options => options
        .Using<double>(ctx => CompareDoubleApprox(ctx, myExpectedObject.Name))
        .WhenTypeIs<double>()
);

...

public void CompareDoubleApprox(IAssertionContext<double> ctx, string Scope)
{
    bool IsDoubleOrInfinite = (double.IsNaN(ctx.Expectation) || double.IsInfinity(ctx.Expectation));
    bool absoluteErrorOK = Math.Abs(ctx.Subject - ctx.Expectation) < ABS_ERROR;

    Execute.Assertion
         .BecauseOf(ctx.Reason, ctx.ReasonArgs)
         .ForCondition(IsDoubleOrInfinite || absoluteErrorOK)
         .FailWith("{3}: Expected {context:double} to be {0} +/- {1} {reason}, but found {2}", ctx.Subject, ABS_ERROR, ctx.Expectation, Scope);
}
```

My assert dump looks like:

> "MyObjectName": Expected member Foo.Bar to be 0 +/-  1E-05 ,
>   but found 1,39675
>
> "MyObjectName": Expected member Foo.FooBar to be 2,07781 +/-  1E-05 ,
>   but found 2,98412
>
> ...More assertion fails...

And I want it to print the objectName **just one time**, before printing all the fails.

**UPDATE>>>>**

The behaviour I want is not implemented yet on github: https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/issues/310. Is marked as a enhancement. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested stab in the dark, but might something like this work:

```
myActualObject.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(myExpectedObject, options => options
    .Using<double>(dbl =>
       { 
           if (!double.IsNaN(dbl.Subject))
           {
               String errorMessage = string.Format("{0} caused the assertion to fail",myExpectedObject);
               dbl.Subject.Should().BeApproximately(dbl.Expectation, ABS_ERROR, errorMessage);
           }
       })
    .WhenTypeIs<double>()
);
```

Comment: It works! now just need to know how to print the name of the object that caused the assertion fail.

Comment: it depends on the test runner you are using.  How are you running the tests? Try switching it for `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: I want it to print in the same scope that the assertion, like the system one: `Assert.IsNotNull(myActualObject, "myActualObjec is null");`

Comment: @Kirenenko can't you just replace the `ABS_ERROR` with the name of the component that failed then?

Comment: `ABS_ERROR` is a double value(0.00001 in this case) to make the comparison. It has nothing to do with the object name.

Comment: @Kirenenko apologies forgot that method needs two parameters, in that case you can use the because argument I think which all fluent assertions methods provide, see my edit

Comment: I think that is not the proper spot to put the object name, see my assertion fail dump: `Expected value 2,07781827340694 to approximate 922,984126984127 +/- 
9,99999974737875E-06 because OBJECT_NAME, but it differed by 920,90630871072.`

Comment: It is not Implemented yet(https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/issues/310). Ill mark this aswer as valid, thanks for your help.